# WinRT use Vector Images for logos

Tags: svg, windows-runtime, graphical-logo

While I have read in the Microsoft guidelines that we should prefer SVG images over raster images I cannot seem to find anywhere how to use them for the logos in the manifest. Does anyone know if this possible?

Comment: [citation required].  The app manifest only allows png and jpeg images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans already mentioned only PNG and JPEG images are supported. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx)'s official documentation on the matter containing complete info on image sizes as well.

Comment: Thanks. It seems silly to have to make all those different sizes for same image, when a vector could be used once and resized perfectly. Oh well, thanks for the confirmation.